# Rename variables in a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, rename

I have the following data and I want to rename the three variable-names inside the column Categories from:

Comment: Instead of giving us the code you are using for your plot, give us a sample of your data. For example, `dput(head(mydata, n = 20))` prints an output into the console that you can copy into your question. Then, any of us can copy it into R to reconstruct your data quickly.

Comment: `sub("\\.\\.\\..*$", "", x)`, where `x` is your column.

Comment: Or use `dplyr::recode`

Comment: Please post a sample of your data and not an image. I cannot copy data out of that image to test my code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sim_long1 %>% 
           mutate( Categories = case_when(
                                    Categories == "Ave...C "~ "Ave",
                                    Categories ==  "Min...C" ~ "Min",
                                    Categories == "Max...C"~ "Max"
                                   )
                           )
```

Hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to just remove `...C..` business from each of the items.  If they are all the same, you can relabel like this:

```
Sim_long1$Categories <- gsub("...C..", "", Sim_long1$Categories
```

Then, plot as normally.  If you want a more general format you could use this type of syntax:

```
Sim_long1$Categories <- gsub('\\.*C*','', Sim_long1$Categories)
```